# Regex / sed - how to match the last space character in a line before a 72 character limit

Tags: regex, git, sed, git-commit

I'm trying to write a command that will format a text file for git commit messages by inserting a line break after character 72 in any relevant lines, but not in the middle of words. If character 72 is in the middle of a word the line break should be inserted at the last space in the line before character 72. The following:

```
sed -e "s/.\{72\}/&\n/g" < msg.md
```

will do the insertion at position 72 regardless of word boundaries, but I can't think how to get it to take account of these boundaries properly.

It could be done with a more complex bash/python script or something to go through each line, but I'm curious if it can be done entirely in regex / sed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed 'y/ /³/
 s/.*/\
&³/
:space
 s/\(.*\n\)\([^³]\{0,72\}\)³/\1\2 /
 t space
 s/\(.*\) \([^³]*³\)/\1\
\2/
 t space
 s/.\(.*\)./\1/
 ' YourFile
```

- posix version so `--posix` on GNU sed
- assume there is no `³` inside, if there are: use another delimiter or translate it firste, and back at the end
- recursive pass on each part until there are no more "maximmu but less than 72 char of word followed by a space"

**Explaination:**

- preparation of string for recursive modification by replacing each space by a non space char (`³` here) + adding a starting new line and a trailing `³`
- select any header followed by a new line (so normaly the last new line, sed taking the biggest part available) followed by the maximum charactere (until 72) that are not `³` followed by a `³` and replace by the same except last `³` by a space char (in fact, i use 2 group but 1 is enough, it stay from earlier test)
- if there is a replacement, retry a new occurance (so it reach the maximum available before a "final" space), if not continue
- take a header (all char from begining of the full string [not the current substring]) followed by a space (so the last available in the current string state) followed by a group of non `³` and a `³` and replace it by the first group, the space by a new line and than the second group
- if there is a replacement, retry the whole cycle
- remove extra part added at the start (first char [a new line], last char)

Do the same for each line, sed taking line by line

Comment: Thanks. Does this work for you on a file containing the line "Make changes to user class to perform extra login validation from certain ips"? This has 77 characters and character 72 is the 'i' of certain, so the line break should come before 'certain', but when I run your command the break is inserted before 'ips'.

Comment: right, i change a bit the code. It take the space later and not earlier :-(

Comment: Thanks it works! Do you think you could explain how it recursively works on each line? I'd like to understand that bit.

Comment: I will adapt the post for more explanaition

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
sed 's/.\{72\}[^[:blank:]]*[[:blank:]]*/&\n/g' msg.md
```

`[^[:blank:]]*` will match 0 or more non-spaces after 72 characters followed by `[[:blank:]]*` which is zero or more spaces.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Don't think it's quite what I need though. If a line in msg.md is like so:

"...change user class to perform login validation"

and character 72 is the 'l' of 'validation', I want the command to insert the newline before the start of 'validation', which will be at character 69, to ensure all lines are < 72 chars but word boundaries are preserved.

Comment: I suggest keeping it simple. This will insert newline after `validation` so sometimes you may get few chars more than 72 until a space is matched.

Comment: Yes it may be practically ok even if not ideal.